# Task name shows wrong pattern even it matches correctly in the YAML file

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

What is wrong in the task name of the below script:

[image]

I am writing the YAML Script for Data Copy from Local Postgre SQL Database to Azure PostgreSQL DB Instance through Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipelines but getting the syntax error

**Code**:

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: CopyData
  jobs:
  - job: CopyDataJob
    displayName: 'Copy Data from Local PostgreSQL to Azure PostgreSQL'
    steps:
    - task: PostgreSQLScript@0
      displayName: 'Export Data from Local PostgreSQL'
      inputs:
        connectionType: 'PostgreSQL'
        postgresqlFile: 'location.sql'
        postgresqlConnectionString: 'DATABASE_URL=postgres://{testuser2408}:{testuser2408!}@{localhost}:{5432}/{postgres}'
        failOnScriptError: true

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Exported Data to Artifact Staging Directory'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        Contents: 'path/to/exported_data/*.csv'
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: Where did you find the name of the task PostgreSQLSecript@0? I don't believe there is a native ADO task for this...thus the error

Comment: Hi @DreadedFrost, Yep, I found in the chatGPT because don't know the steps of copying local postgresql db to Azure postgresql database using CI/Cd Pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this error is occurring is due to the fact there is no task PostgreSQLScript@0 task available.

For deploying to an Azure PostgreSQL Server Microsoft recommends leveraging the [AzureCLI@2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/azure-pipelines-deploy-database-task)

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Azure CLI
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: <Name of the Azure Resource Manager service connection>
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    arguments:
      -SERVERNAME mydemoserver `
      -DBNAME pollsdb `
      -DBUSER pollsdbuser`
      -DBPASSWORD pollsdbpassword
    inlineScript: |
      az login --allow-no-subscription
      az postgres flexible-server execute --name $(SERVERNAME) \
      --admin-user $(DBUSER) --admin-password '$(DBPASSWORD)' \
      --database-name $(DBNAME) --file-path /code/sql/db-schema-update.sql
```